# Findidng sum of object excluding few keys

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
Result = [{"01": 330,"02": 353,"03": 178,"04": 353,"KID": 10,"PID": 5},
          {"01": 320,"02": 112,"03": 328,"04": 123,"KID": 11,"PID": 6},
          {"01": 110,"02": 253,"03": 375,"04": 233,"KID": 12,"PID": 7}]
```

I know how to do sum of all keys like below:

```
Result.forEach(item =>{
    let sum = Object.keys(item).reduce((acc,value) => acc + item[value],0);
       item["total"] = sum;
    })
```

how do i find the sum of values excluding `"KID"` and `"PID"` keys?

Comment: do you have always the same amount of keys? do you know it in advance?

Comment: add `filter` before `reduce`

Comment: Run a `filter` after the `keys` call: `.filter(k => k != "PID" && k != "KID")`

Comment: You could call `filter()` on the keys array.

Comment: Instead of `filter`, you can simply change your `reduce` to something like: `acc + (value == "KID" || value == "PID" ? 0 : item[value])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter the keys.

```js
var result = [{ "01": 330, "02": 353, "03": 178, "04": 353, "KID": 10, "PID": 5 }, { "01": 320, "02": 112, "03": 328, "04": 123, "KID": 11, "PID": 6 }, { "01": 110, "02": 253, "03": 375,"04": 233, "KID": 12, "PID": 7 }];

result.forEach(item => item.total = Object
    .keys(item)
    .filter(k => k !== 'KID' && k !== 'PID')
    .reduce((s, k) => s + item[k], 0)
);

console.log(result);
```

Or you could take the keys in advance and sum only with the wanted keys.

```js
var result = [{ "01": 330, "02": 353, "03": 178, "04": 353, "KID": 10, "PID": 5 }, { "01": 320, "02": 112, "03": 328, "04": 123, "KID": 11, "PID": 6 }, { "01": 110, "02": 253, "03": 375,"04": 233, "KID": 12, "PID": 7 }],
    exclude = ['KID', 'PID'],
    keys = Object.keys(result[0]).filter(k => !exclude.includes(k));

result.forEach(item => item.total = keys.reduce((s, k) => s + item[k], 0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could do it.

```js
Result = [{"01": 330,"02": 353,"03": 178,"04": 353,"KID": 10,"PID": 5},
          {"01": 320,"02": 112,"03": 328,"04": 123,"KID": 11,"PID": 6},
          {"01": 110,"02": 253,"03": 375,"04": 233,"KID": 12,"PID": 7}]

// Execlude someKeys, if they are available in the array then they will be execluded.
var execludedKeys = ["PID", "KID"];
Result.forEach(item =>{
let sum = Object.keys(item).reduce((acc,value) =>
 execludedKeys.indexOf(value) == -1 ? (acc + item[value]) : acc
  ,0);
  item["total"] = sum;
});
    
    console.log(Result)
```

Comment: ++ for taking an array for excluding keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.entries` instead and then do `if` check.

```js
const data = [{"01": 330,"02": 353,"03": 178,"04": 353,"KID": 10,"PID": 5}, {"01": 320,"02": 112,"03": 328,"04": 123,"KID": 11,"PID": 6}, {"01": 110,"02": 253,"03": 375,"04": 233,"KID": 12,"PID": 7}]
          
data.forEach(obj => {
  obj.total = Object.entries(obj)
    .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
      if (k != 'KID' && k != 'PID') r += obj[k]
      return r
    }, 0)
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

add filter after read object keys

```
.filter(k=>!['KID','PID'].includes(k))
```

```js
let Result = [{"01": 330,"02": 353,"03": 178,"04": 353,"KID": 10,"PID": 5},
          {"01": 320,"02": 112,"03": 328,"04": 123,"KID": 11,"PID": 6},
          {"01": 110,"02": 253,"03": 375,"04": 233,"KID": 12,"PID": 7}]
          
Result.forEach(item =>{
    item["total"] = Object.keys(item).filter(k=>!['KID','PID'].includes(k))
                     .reduce((acc,value) => acc + item[value],0);
})
    
console.log(Result);
```